# How can i find the controls those have higher tab index than a specific control in c# win form 2.0?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am not sure if this question has been asked earlier. As the question stated, I can get the collection of all controls in a win form (through **Controls.Find()** method). Now, say I have a **TextBox** control with **tab index=5**, I need to **find** the controls those have **tab index > 5**. I am not sure how or where to start. That's why I can't paste any code segment. Hope that's OK.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You may use LINQ

```
var controls = this.Controls
                    .Cast<Control>()
                    .Where(r => r.TabIndex > 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `TabIndex` property of the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code, where TextBox1 is the name of the TextBox

```
for (int i = 5; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
{
    if (tabControl1.TabPages[i] != null)
    {
        var textBox = tabControl1.TabPages[i].Controls.Find("TextBox1", false);
        //...
    }       
}
```